# Need assistance regarding shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([string isEqualToString:@" "] || [string isEqualToString:@"@"] || [string isEqualToString:@"!"] || [string isEqualToString:@"#"] || [string isEqualToString:@"$"] || [string isEqualToString:@"%"] || [string isEqualToString:@"^"] || [string isEqualToString:@"&"] || [string isEqualToString:@"*"] || [string isEqualToString:@"("] || [string isEqualToString:@")"] || [string isEqualToString:@"+"] || [string isEqualToString:@"-"])
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

I am using this method to restrict all these characters. It works fine when user types text from keyboard. If user paste text or use siri to enter text nothing happens.

How to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to customize your delegate method like this:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([string isEqualToString:@" "] || [string isEqualToString:@"@"] || [string isEqualToString:@"!"] || [string isEqualToString:@"#"] || [string isEqualToString:@"$"] || [string isEqualToString:@"%"] || [string isEqualToString:@"^"] || [string isEqualToString:@"&"] || [string isEqualToString:@"*"] || [string isEqualToString:@"("] || [string isEqualToString:@")"] || [string isEqualToString:@"+"] || [string isEqualToString:@"-"])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if([string length] > 1)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"@!!#$%^&*()+-@%"];
        NSString *resultString = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        textField.text = resultString;
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If I paste "How are you", this is what I am getting "HowareyouHow are you".

Comment: thanks for answer. Please can you also explain how its working and why it was giving the odd behaviour.

Comment: While pasting the string ShouldChangeCharactersInRange delegate method fire with entire string. So here we filter after the unwanted character and set the filter string to the selected text field programmatically and return NO(It doesn't paste the original content)

Answer (score 2):

When you enter text through keyboard, *shouldChangeCharactersInRange* gives you single characters in *string* parameter for every entry. When you paste it or enter through *siri*, it gives you whole string or words that have been added. In your case, you are comparing string as a single character which fails in paste and siri case.. I have written code snippet for you. Try it and tell me whether it works or not. It basically removes special characters from string.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([string length] > 0)
    {
         NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:\"<>?,./;'[]-="];
         NSString *resultString = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
         textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textField.text, resultString];
         return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this code do not allow to delete characters using the delete button on keyboard.

Comment: you are not using resultstring any where. So i repalce string with resultstring in third line.

Comment: oh yes.. I forgot to mention delete case.. now i have edited answer.. try now

Answer (score 0):

You current code only checks for equality with single character. Paste string can contain more than one character. You can do filtering of strings with character set:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *invalidCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" @!#$%%^&*()+-"];
    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invalidCharacters].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        textField.text = [[newText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharacters] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code do not even allow to paste text that contain any restricted character.

Comment: @S.J updated my code to replace invalid characters if they are found.

Answer (score 0):

#define Alpha_Numeric @" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_."

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

        NSCharacterSet *charSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:Alpha_Numeric] invertedSet];

        NSString *resStr = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return [string isEqualToString:resStr];
    }
```